# Vaadin : CustomLayout don't generate <div> content

Tags: java, html, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 7. When I try to add html content to CustomLayout it does not generate a paragraph inside a div element. Here is the input :

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 50px;" class="col-lg-10">
<div class="bs-component">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Myprofile" class="active"
            data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#setting" data-toggle="tab">setting</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabbable">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="Myprofile" location="Myprofile" class="tab-pane active"></div>
            <div id="setting" location="setting" class="tab-pane">
                <p>My paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In java I use this :

```
String html; //This var contain my input
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());         
CustomLayout custom = null;
            try {
                custom = new CustomLayout(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Finaly I add the customLayout to my mainLayout. When I run the application I get this output :

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 50px;" class="col-lg-10">
<div class="bs-component">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Myprofile" class="active"
            data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#setting" data-toggle="tab">setting</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabbable">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="Myprofile" location="Myprofile" class="tab-pane active"></div>
            <div id="setting" location="setting" class="tab-pane">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My paragraph inside div with id=setting was not generated by Vaadin. Any Ideas to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem. I removed the location="setting" part in the div element and it worked. I don't know why It does that. Probably because CustomLayout when generating the html looks for elements to put in the location, if it does not find one it clean all the element content.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need the location="setting" attribute? Don't you insert a component for that attribute?

Comment: Actually the html is generated automaticaly following my needs. I managed the problem this way: when I need the location, I generate the <div> element with the location propertie, otherwise I don't.